# Conector PostgreSQL con C#

Tags: postgresql

Me gustaría saber cual es el mejor conector para enlazar C# con Postgres libre, claro porque no nombrar uno bueno de pago que no sea muy caro.

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede hacerlo de dos formas. 
1) Si lo que necesita es conectarse a Postgrees desde el código. Es muy fácil y gratis. Solo debe agregar a su proyecto el Nuget que se llama Npgsql, para lo cual debe usar al Gestor de Paquetes Nuget
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y de ahí en adelante es solo cuestión de agregarlo como un using en la clase donde esta trabajando.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta dirección esta la información mas clara: [Conectar aplicación .NET a PostgreSQL](https://www.genbetadev.com/cnet/conectar-nuestra-aplicacion-net-a-postgresql-entidades-y-conectores)

2) Pero si lo que busca es que le aparezca en el "Server explorer" entonces debe 
usar una extensión que hasta donde se, funciona bien en 2015 y 2017. De las anteriores no tengo información, la puede encontrar en: [Npgsql PostgreSQL Integration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RojanskyS.NpgsqlPostgreSQLIntegration)

Comment: Ok, gracias, mi gran pregunta, ¿Es este el mejor conector gratuito?

Comment: @Karajal Si todo es gratis

Comment: @Karakal es el mejor conector ya que lo provve el mismo fabricante de la base de datos